# Force developers to write comment on methods in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, code-coverage

As everyone knows, `commenting the methods` in enterprise projects cause to have more readable codes, but some developers like me forget to do it, I heard that in `VS 2015` we have an option that can use, which forces developer to write a comment. I searched about it, but didn't find any result! 
Can anyone help me?

NOTE: Please tell me if you know any third party application which can help in this case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually everybody does not agree with your premise. Rather than comments a better approach is to create readable code. You might want to read http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you're looking for is called StyleCop which has now been updated to use the Roslyn compiler.

The github repo is [here](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) and there are various README files for configuration including [this one](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md#documentation-requirements) that highlights the specific documentation feature you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your answering,  its sound is really good, i should try it, i'll  tell u the result, if it works i will mark u as answer.

Comment: can u look at to this : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407071/using-stylecop-in-as-net-core`