# Using StyleCop in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, stylecop

According to this [this article](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/DotNetCli.md) for using StyleCop in Asp.net Core,

1)Add the following to the dependencies section of the project.json file:

```
 "StyleCop.Analyzers": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "build"
}
```

and build the project.

2) Create `stylecop.json` and add your configuration on it, this is my `stylecop.json` content:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
   "settings": {
     "documentationRules": {
       "documentInterfaces": true,
       "documentInternalMembers": false    
   }
  }
 }
```

3) the following under the buildOptions node in the project.json file:

```
  "additionalArguments": ["/additionalfile:path/to/stylecop.json" ]
```

but i got some errors: what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: What is the path of stylecop.json? Where is stylecop.json located in your solution that path you will have to mention in additionalfile.

Comment: Also, while building project make sure the Error List output is set to `Build + IntelliSense`

Comment: I change addtionalArguments to ` "additionalArguments": [ "stylecop.json" ]`, but it gives me another error: `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected`

Comment: Try like this - `"additionalArguments": ["/additionalfile: stylecop.json"]`

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

Those `NullReferenceException` errors happen when StyleCop cannot find your `stylecop.json`. Here is the [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/2073).

To fix it (assuming that your `stylecop.json` is in the root of your project) change the path to this:

```
"additionalArguments": [
  "/additionalfile:./stylecop.json"
]
```

## Full Working Example

Directory structure

```
bin
obj
Program.cs
project.json
project.lock.json
stylecop.json
StyleCop.ruleset
```

Project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "warningsAsErrors": true,
    "nowarn": [
      "1591"
    ],
    "xmlDoc": true,
    "additionalArguments": [
      "/ruleset:./StyleCop.ruleset",
      "/additionalfile:./stylecop.json"   <----- This is probably the problem.
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "StyleCop.Analyzers": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

stylecop.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "documentationRules": {
      "documentExposedElements": false,
      "documentInterfaces": false
    }
  }
}
```

StyleCop.ruleset

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description=" " ToolsVersion="14.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="StyleCop.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="StyleCop.Analyzers">
    <Rule Id="SA0000" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="SA1005" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="SA1208" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="SA1028" Action="Warning" />
    <Rule Id="SA1210" Action="Warning" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

## Clone and Run the Example

```
git clone git@github.com:bigfont/StackOverflow.git
cd .\StackOverflow\AspNetCoreStyleCop\
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

Comment: When i want create `StyleCop.ruleset` it gives me error `Data at the root level is invalid`.

Comment: Why? I do as u said, it doesn't let me to edit it too, and give me same error

Comment: @ShaunLuttin A very happy new year! Just taking advantage of this question- Is it necessary to provide `StyleCop.ruleset` file?

Comment: @Sanket Happy new year to you too. The `StyleCop.ruleset` is not required.

Comment: @pejman I don't know what the XML error is that you have introduced. I added the example to GitHub for you (see the answer's edits). Try that and see if you experience the same error.